# How do I achieve a horizontal list of avatars in Zurb Foundation 5.5?

Tags: zurb-foundation-5

I would like to add a number of avatars spaced equally and horizontally with the "Add" icon at the end. How can I achieve this in Zurb Foundation 5.5? I'm also using AngularJS.

Apologies I'm still quite new to the framework. Would I use a grid?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can use the block grid:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html

You simply loop through the images and right after the loop you can render a final `<li>ADD Button</li>`

## Or... you can use Clearing

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/clearing.html

Again looping through the images and right after the loop render the final `<li>ADD Button</li>`

Comment: Thanks, block grid did it.

Comment: :) You're welcome... I use the block grid quite extensively to render administration forms